# Sticky header jumps on fast scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ecmascript-6

I have problem with sticky header. I have placeholder to keep good height when i am scrolling and it's working fine. Problem appear when i scroll faster. I read that jquery scroll position by 1-2-4-12.. pixels at once and by it my sticky header stick not on position i wanted what couse something like jump or blink.

```
scroll() {
  let queryWindow = Ember.$(window);
  let siteBarHeight = Ember.$('.folded').offset() ? 19 : 47;

  queryWindow.scroll(() => {
    let fixedHeader = this.get('fixedHeader');
    let shouldBeFixed = queryWindow.scrollTop() > 90 + siteBarHeight;

    if (!fixedHeader && shouldBeFixed) {
      this.set('fixedHeader', true);
    } else if (fixedHeader && !shouldBeFixed) {
      this.set('fixedHeader', false);
    }
  });
}
```

This all working fine when my scroll slowly, but in other way jquery stick it too late. Thanks in advance for helping me, tell me if you need more information about it.

Comment: You may simply setInterval(..,100) , as scroll events can trigger very often -> cause lagging

Comment: trigger your function only when you cross the 90px point, that means, check your last scrollTop and compare with current

Comment: I have to set property 'fixedHeader' only and my other logic do the rest. Problem is that jquery/plain javascript catch this change to late when i scroll fast. I recorded it on slow motion and i saw that my normal header during fast scrolling disapear for about 0,3s and than he changes to fixed and looks normal. Just this 0,3s looks like website blink or jump.